# Scalapack not present in Intel MKL on OSX?

Tags: macos, fortran, intel, scalapack, intel-composer

I installed ifort composer 2013 SP1 update 1 (103) on OSX 10.8, but apparently I don't have scalapack libraries. Is scalapack not provided on OSX (it is on linux/win) or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Still I believe the official support forum is a better place for these questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it's not included for OS X. I looked on my machine and couldn't find it included with ifort or MKL. So I did some searching.

[Intel Documentation](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/mklman/GUID-1C7A97AF-0177-48CC-BE0E-F228531C5FEE.htm)

> ScaLAPACK routines are provided only with Intel® MKL versions for
>   Linux* and Windows* OSs.

Comment: And we have a winner... it's what I suspected. Thank you for finding it out.

Comment: I suspect that this is down to the lack of an Intel MPI for OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Intel added ScaLAPACK support on OS X (MacOS) in 2015...
be sure to select "cluster support" (not default) during installation.
It is there - even for the community (free) version.
If you did not select "cluster support" - just rerun the installation,
and select "modify installation" and check the box.

See https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-math-kernel-library/topic/506885 for the Intel response announcing the addition of ScaLAPACK for OS X in 2015.